# Am I able to unlock taunts as random or achievement drops?

Tags: team-fortress-2

The title should be self explanatory. On team fortress 2, am I able to unlock taunts like the conga, square dance, Rock Paper Scissors etc etc, as random or achievement drops?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, the only taunts that are in the random drop system are the Schadenfreude and High Five.

They seem to be part of the Hat drop table, meaning that they are rare drops.

The only taunt that is unlockable by an achievement is the [Director's Vision](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Director%27s_Vision), which is unlocked by using the Replay Editor for the first time.

Edit: The TF2 Wiki seems to think that all taunts (except Director's Vision) have a chance of dropping.  Personally, I've never seen any of them drop.

If you really want a taunt, your best bet is trading for it.

Comment: Well that is lame. I am sick of getting only weapons. I can't trade anything i get. If only valve would put more into the drop systems than weapons.

Comment: @AndrewEckert Valve limits the amount of items available so that people will just buy the items from the Mann Co. Store. It's all just a sick plot to make money...

Comment: EatMyTacoCrumbs isn't 100% wrong, but isn't completely right either. A large part of the economy of TF2 comes from the fact that people can buy items for cash, and then turn them around for trade.

@AndrewEckert  Getting a ton of weapon drops might not be a great thing at the moment, but creating metal scraps/reclaim/refined is the main point of this. Check out some of the trading sites to trade your metal in for items you DO want like taunts.

Comment: You don't understand. I can't trade random drop weapons.

Comment: I also wish that you could test run other items rather than weapons.

Comment: You can get cosmetics (and more rarely taunts) as rarer drops, but only if you have a premium account.  To get a premium account, you have to buy at least one item from the Mann Co. Store in game.  Incidentally, Premium accounts can also trade items.

Comment: And by more rarely, I mean you'll be lucky to get one cosmetic in six months.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need yo actually buy things for a premium account. You can sell Steam cards to get store credit and buy things from TF2, and the game considers it a purchase and gives a premium account.

Comment: If this is true, this is a change from how it used to work.  It used to have to be an item from the Mann Co. Store and is still documented as such in the [TF2 F2P FAQ](http://www.teamfortress.com/freetoplay/faq.php).